# changing $scope Angular variable through a seperate JavaScript event listener

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an angular `HTML` file, an `angularjs` controller file and a simple `JavaScript` file.

Angular HTML file is something like

```
<section data-ng-controller="myCtrl">

    {{name}}

    <button id="btn1">Button1</button>

</section>
```

Angularjs controller file is like

```
angular.module('users').controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope) {

    $scope.name="HELLO";

}]);
```

and a simple JavaScript file like

```
<script>
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click",function(){

    // code????? that can change the $scope.name variable to "changed"

});
</script>
```

the html file will initially look like

```
HELLO
<button>
```

I want the functionality that on clicking the button it should change to something like

```
changed
<button>
```

Is there any way to change the $scope variable in angular part from a separate JavaScript file containing a regular event listener?

How to code the JavaScript part for this?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? the click event can be done in angular too.

Comment: i have 100 lines of same code in 4 different angular controllers so i was thinking to put that in a separate file..

Comment: what does separate file have to do with anything...just making more work for yourself. Could put all the functions in a service also which would make binding to controllers very simple

Comment: Indeed, there can be a service or a directive that would remove duplications, but messing javascript with angular soon will get messy and unmanageable.

Comment: Ok i am a newbie and just thought of this way to reduce duplications. i will try the service way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access an Angular scope through an element directly.

```js
//Angular code
var myApp = angular.module('users', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope) {
    $scope.name="HELLO";
}]);

//External code
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  var $scope = angular.element(e.target).scope();
  
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.name = 'Changed';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="users" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{name}}
    <button id="btn1">Button1</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt angular function ng-click to achieve the same,

Your HTMl will be:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div> {{ name}}</div>

  <input type="submit" ng-click="btn()" value="button"></input>

</div>
```

Your angular js code will be:

```
var myApp = angular.module('users', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.name="HELLO";

   $scope.btn = function () {
     $scope.name = "Changed";
   };
}]);
```

You can find the working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vamshhi/810c0704/)

Comment: i want to achieve this functionality by using a seperate javascript file for the event listener

Comment: Drew Gaynor already posted that, so I posted the other method